# Windows 7 Desktop icons turned off after every reboot

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

I have a windows 7 x64 laptop, and every time I reboot all icons on my desktop are missing.  I can get them back by right clicking on the desktop and selecting View -> Show Desktop Icons, but I'd prefer they stayed on.

Is there a setting or known problem I should be looking at to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I found some tips:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3659-desktop-items-hide-show.html
Guessing that your problem could be solved by changing the setting to show icons as you have and then save your theme.
You can do that by right clicking on the desktop and pick one of the alternatives at the end of the list. Afraid that I can't be more specific since I'm working at a computer with XP at the moment.
Good luck

Comment: Giving this a go, will know after I reboot if it has worked. Thanks!